# How to trigger a python script whenever new data is loaded into a s3 bucket?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to pull down data from an s3 bucket that gets new records by the second. Data comes in at 250+ G per hour. I am creating a Python script that will be running continuously to collect new data loads in real-time by **the seconds**.

Here is the structure of the s3 bucket keys:

```
o_key=7111/year=2020/month=8/day=11/hour=16/minute=46/second=9/ee9.jsonl.gz
o_key=7111/year=2020/month=8/day=11/hour=16/minute=40/second=1/ee99999.jsonl.gz
```

I am using Boto3 to try and attempt this and here is what I have so far:

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY, verify=False)
s3_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
files = s3_bucket.objects.filter()
files = [obj.key for obj in sorted(files, key=lambda x: x.last_modified, reverse=True)]
for x in files:
    print(x)
```

This outputs all the keys that are in that bucket and sorts by the last_modified data. However is there a way to pause the script until new data is loaded and then process that data and so on **by the second**? There could be 20 second delays when loaded in the new data so that is another thing that is giving me troubles when forming the logic. Any ideas or suggestions would help.

```
 s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY, verify=False)
 s3_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

 files = s3_bucket.objects.filter()
 while list(files): #check if the key exists
         if len(objs) > 0 and objs[0].key == key:
                   print("Exists!")
         else:
               time.sleep(.1) #sleep until the next key is there
               continue
```

This is another approach i tried but isn't working to well. I am trying to sleep whenever there is no next data and then process the new data once it is loaded.

Comment: A much better approach would be to have Amazon S3 trigger an AWS Lambda function whenever a new object is created. Also, if there are many (eg thousands+) objects in the bucket, the listing process will take far too long and would generate too many S3 requests. What are you _actually_ trying to accomplish with all this? There might be a better way to achieve your end-goal rather than listing/sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon S3 notification feature enables you to receive notifications when certain events happen in your bucket. To enable notifications, you must first add a notification configuration that identifies the events you want Amazon S3 to publish and the destinations where you want Amazon S3 to send the notifications.
You store this configuration in the notification subresource that is associated with a bucket. - Typically in Lambda...

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html

Hope this helps 
r0ck