# How to sleep while statement until a condition is met and continue-Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, time, boto3

I am trying to create a script that runs until a certain condition is giving and then continues. I am looping over my s3 bucket using boto3 trying to collect the latest_modified keys to process. I have gotten as far as being able to capture the latest modified key from the bucket but I am having issue on how I can keep looping until the latest modified variable from a run is greater (later date) than the last modified date that was ran.

My solution is if the last_date <= last_ran_date then I should sleep until the last_date is > than the last_date. Here is what I have so far. All the way until the if statement works as excepted but need help on finding a way to store that last_date from a run in a variable so I can use that as the flag for each loop.

**Here is my code:**

```
while True:
    get_last_modified = lambda obj: obj.last_modified
    bckt = s3_resource.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
    objs = [obj for obj in bckt.objects.all()]
    objs = [obj for obj in sorted(objs, key=get_last_modified)]
    last_added = objs[-1].key
    last_date = objs[-1].last_modified

    if last_date <= last_date:
        time.sleep(1)
    elif last_date > last_date:
        print('this is a new one {}'.format(last_added))
```

Any ideas or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This condition `last_date <= last_date` will always be true since it is comparing the variable to itself. Maybe you meant to create two variables? Also the way to write this using a while loop would be `while <condition you are testing>:` instead of `while True:` with a further conditional.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to accomplish... are you trying to find the file in the bucket with the most recently modified date?  once you find it, what do you want to do with it?  when does processing stop?

Comment: Could you please edit your question explain _why_ you are wanting to do this? Will the Python program _always_ be running, and it should wait until it sees that there is a new file added since a previous "run time"? _WHY_ are you wanting to do this? Once it is found, _what_ do you intend to do with the file? If you wish to process "new files", a much easier way would be to configure Amazon S3 to trigger an AWS Lambda function when a new file is added. (This seems to match your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63490784).)